# php_dbx extension

Tags: php, database, dbx

It seems like PHP have removed dbx-extension as default install since version 5.
I am wondering, why? Is dbx out?

And where can I download the extension, I did google, but I can't find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dbx.php):

> This extension has been moved to the » PECL repository and is no
>   longer bundled with PHP as of PHP 5.1.0.

PDO offers the same sort of functionality (single interface to multiple database types) so I assume you're expected to use that instead.